# Fresh Anaconda Navigator install, Jupyter notebook keeps showing connection error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm brand new to coding and have downloaded Anaconda to use Jupyter Notebook. However, I keep getting an error, cannot connect to network. I have looked around and tried a bunch of different fixes, none of which have worked. I've reinstalled Anaconda several times, tried opening Jupyter at ip=127.0.0.1 port=9999, VPN on and off. It's been a couple days now so I'm really hoping someone can help. Below is what shows up in Anaconda Prompt when I try to open a notebook. Not sure if it's related but Jupyter Notebook also won't launch from Anaconda Navigator, I HAVE to use Anaconda Prompt to launch it. I'm completely new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
      file:///C:/Users/Gerad%20Collingwood/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-22504-open.html
  Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
       http://localhost:8888/?token=2ef67e00adc18a197a353c6807983fc62bd1e5423a3788af
    or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2ef67e00adc18a197a353c6807983fc62bd1e5423a3788af`
`[I 11:22:50.281 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /Python Codes`
`Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)`
[I 11:22:53.527 NotebookApp] Kernel started: cd50ffe9-3bae-48a6-a2a7-9fccfdf64f3d, name: python3
`Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)`
`Exception in thread Thread-4:`
`Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()` 
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)`
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 78, in _thread_main
   self.io_loop.start()`
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
   self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()`
`File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
   self._run_once()` 
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
   event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)`
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
   r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)`
 `File "C:\Users\Gerad Collingwood\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
   r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)`
`OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: So just for clarification: When you open from anaconda prompt, all is fine. When opened from the navigator, nothing works. Also connecting from your browser directly using `http://127.0.0.1:8888` (Note that the port should be **8888**, not **9999**) does not work and displays the error message you ahve posted?

Comment: Hey thanks for clarifying. Yeh opening from the navigator, Jupyter notebooks doesn't even open. From anaconda prompt, the jupyter notebooks program will open but I can't open or create a new notebook because the network connection error comes up. Connecting directly, (using either port 8888 or 9999) also doesn't help. @FlyingTeller

Comment: Do you have your own installation of `zeromq` (@ `C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what zeromq is. Should I have my own installation of that?

Comment: I don't think so. I searched for any files with zeromq in the file name and the only ones that came back were associated with the anaconda install. @FlyingTeller

Comment: That is good. Can you try to specify the ip and port in anaconda prompt like this: `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.X --port=9999` and report if that changes anything?

Comment: I just tried this, unfortunately no luck. Same error as before came up. As this is/seems to be a networking issue, I'm wondering if the fact I'm located in China is an issue? Could the great firewall be interfering? @FlyingTeller

Comment: That sounds unlikely. You are only connecting to the jupyter kernel that is running locally on your computer. That would work even if you were not connected to the internet at all.

Comment: I created a new user account on my computer, this time a name without a space. It solved the issue of opening Jupyter Notebook through the Anaconda Navigator, may have just been a preferences issue for how to open .html files. Still no luck connecting to the notebook server though, still comes up with the same bad address error as before. @FlyingTeller

Comment: I FINALLY managed to get it working. It seems to have been an issue with the version of pyzmq. I found the solution here https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_53396071/article/details/113782733

I used the following that is shown in the link. In Anaconda prompt 'pip uninstall pyzmq' and then after uninstalling I installed version 19.0.2 by 'pip install pyzmq==19.0.2'

After going back to jupyter notebook via the navigator it worked without any issue at all. Thanks for the help @FlyingTeller you gave me hope where I had almost given up